# Android: Activity rotation is done but orientation at configuration is not changed

Tags: android

Android: Activity rotation is done but orientation at configuration is not changed.

So, When I called Dialog wiht landscape layout after rotation, the dialog didn't show landscape layout.

Why did that?

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Timber.d("onConfigurationChanged: ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE")
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Timber.d("onConfigurationChanged: ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT")
    }

    Timber.d("resources.configuration.orientation: ${resources.configuration.orientation}")

}
```

result log:

```
onConfigurationChanged: ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
resources.configuration.orientation: 1
```